# Help me identify this BIG Robot Movie from 80s

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

I can't remember anything about the movie except it giant robots like Pacific Rim but people were inside not sat down but stood up using their arms and legs - I don't know properly but was like some kind of pilot - I remember a guy hooked up controlling the robot and a woman behind him telling him what to do.

The Giant robot would battle other robots with other people inside.

That's it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Robot Jox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Jox).

It's 1980s (well, technically released 1990 but filmed in 1987), features giant robots and the protagonists are indeed standing, rather than directly attenuated to the robots.

Comment: I feel this is it - seems similar to what I was looking for. See I can I find this. Thanks Richard :)

Comment: 1990 is the final year of the 80s decade, since in the Gregorian calendar we do not have a year zero. So each decade begins with a year ending in the numeral 1. Hence the first decade of the Gregorian calendar was A.D. year 1 through year 10, the decade of the 80s began in 1981, and concluded with 1990, and the current Gregorian millennium began January 1st, 2001. So *Robot Jox* was indeed in the 80s. :)